# Angular 1.x - filtering objects called by a reference ID

Tags: angularjs, filter, reference

Hello intelligent and caring community.

I'd like to know if there's an Angular way to filter object properties when that object is called via a repeat of object keys in an array.

This is a contrived example but important because my app is running firebase and I use an index to collect object ids of specific users.

Example:

```js
angular.module('stackOverflowExample', []).controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myObjectKeysArray = [
    'sdav', 'arfg', 'wefc'
  ];
  $scope.myObject = {
    sdav: {name:'mark', age:23},
    arfg: {name:'lucy', age:18},
    wefc: {name:'kat', age:19},
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="stackOverflowExample" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <label>
    <span>Search</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search">

  </label>
  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="objectKey in myObjectKeysArray | filter:search" placeholder="search">
    <p>name: {{ myObject[objectKey].name }}</p>
    <p>age: {{ myObject[objectKey].age }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone recommend a sweet way to do this or should I just make an array before calling repeat?

Comment: Making array would be best, then repeat the array instead of the keys and let filter do what it does by default

Comment: Are you using ES6?

Comment: Yes, @developer033 I'm using es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question well, you want to filter the "subarray", so I merged the array, putting that key as an attribute of its array.

Here's is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObjectKeysArray = [
    'sdav', 'arfg', 'wefc'
  ];

  $scope.myObject = {  
    "sdav":{  
      "name":"mark",
      "age":23
    },
    "arfg":{  
      "name":"lucy",
      "age":18
    },
    "wefc":{  
      "name":"kat",
      "age":19
    }
  };

  $scope.array = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.myObjectKeysArray, function(value, key) {
    $scope.array[key] = {};
    $scope.array[key].key = value;
    $scope.array[key].values = [];
    $scope.array[key].values.push($scope.myObject[value]);
  });      
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <label>
    <span>Search</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  </label>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li ng-bind="arr.key" ng-repeat-start="arr in array" placeholder="search"></li>
    <ul ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="obj in arr.values | filter: { name: search }">
      <li ng-bind="'Name => ' + obj.name"></li>
      <li ng-bind="'Age => ' + obj.age"></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know of a way that we can merge the key on the fly? The reason is that I'm getting an array from firebase and looking to skip the step on the data factory of wrapping them together.

Comment: Hmm, you can't change the data.. then edit your question with a real code, please.

Comment: I edited the question to put the reasoning in the top part, instead of under the snippet. thanks for pointing that out but yeah the question isn't about how to make an array although your example is pretty awesome.

Comment: Well, but can't you provide any real example? Maybe I can help.

Comment: that is a real example. firebaseArray() from the angularfire library returns an array of objects. the only difference is that they include $id property on the array. On the firebase db, i have db.product objects and i have references to those objects for each user saved on the db.user.products array

Comment: it's not a big deal to spin up a new array, just was looking for a sweet way if it existed.

Comment: @markcandaras still far more common to store both as arrays of objects not as objects with sub objects

Comment: @developer033 cheers, i implemented something similar in my service. Thanks for your help!